# Transmiting Small data over 400 ft

Tags: wireless, data-transfer

I'm trying to read thermocouples and transmit a text file with the temperature inside it. I have Thermocouples in a water line and I need to grab the temperature and then send it to a Windows computer, in something like a txt file, not using  something like PuTTy.

So I just need ideas of how to transmit it back either through an RF transmitter or a little WiFi hotspot. I may be using a Raspberry Pi Zero in the final product, but will be using a Raspberry Pi 2 for testing.

Comment: Tyler, welcome to the Raspberry Pi stack exchange.  Your question is currently overly broad, and I'm honestly not particularly sure what you're asking about.  You've listed two good options for transmitting data, are you asking *how* to transmit data in one of those manners, or for alternatives? Either would be considered off topic here. If you have more specific questions about either, please feel free to ask a more detailed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer but just some thoughts (as the question is indeed quite broad):

Low power WiFi solutions such as [nodeMCU](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html) or [ParticleIO](http://www.particle.io) could be used to handle these sensors  and send the data to a central control unit (e.g. a Pi) via a local WiFi. Beneficial is the lower power consumption of those nodes compared to a Pi at each sensor.